# How to add an extra parameter to be sent to the server while using "formDeleting" in jQgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I need to send an extra parameter while I am trying to delete one or more rows in jQgrid. I have found the following:

- [jqGrid additional POST data when deleting row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466059/jqgrid-additional-post-data-when-deleting-row)
- [jqGrid (Delete row) - How to send additional POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833254/jqgrid-delete-row-how-to-send-additional-post-data/7312550)

But those are one/two year old answers and I think jQgrid has changed since then. I am using the `formDeleting` option from jQgrid defined as follow:

```javascript
formDeleting: {
    url: '/ajax/forms/delete',
    delicon: [true, "left", "fa-scissors"],
    cancelicon: [true, "left", "fa-times"],
    width: 320,
    caption: 'Delete form',
    msg: 'Are you sure you want to delete this form?',
    beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
        var rowids = $form.find("#DelData>td").data("rowids");

        if (rowids.length > 1) {
            $form.find("td.delmsg").html('Are you sure you want to delete all the selected forms?');
        }
    },
    afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) {
        if (response.responseText === "true") {
            alert("The form was deleted successfully.", "Information");
        } else {
            alert("Something went wrong, the form could not be deleted.", "Error");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I add an extra parameter to the request so I can get it on the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use [onclickSubmit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.2/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L882) callback close to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466059/jqgrid-additional-post-data-when-deleting-row), but to place the code of the `onclickSubmit` callback inside of `formDeleting`. The usage of [serializeDelData](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.2/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L889) inside of `formDeleting` inside of `formDeleting` is possible too, but it's better to use it in case of more deep changing in the posted data, like the usage of `JSON.stringify`, for example.

Comment: @ReynierPM: Look at https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aw47ytqz/2/ where I added `localReader: { id: "Id" }`, modified the code of `isDisplayButtons` and added the call of `navButtonAdd` at the end of the code.

Comment: `localReader` is because the data is set to by `local` or it's needed if the data is remote as well? This is part of a big grid (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271049/how-to-avoid-jqgrid-initial-ajax-request/48275088#48275088) I just split out my doubts in smaller questions :)

Comment: @ReynierPM: `localReader: { id: "Id" }` is needed if you fills the data via local `data`, but it could be that in some cases of `loadonce: true` scenario it could be helpful too. In any way your previous demo doesn't used `Id` of the source data.

Comment: I am having another issue: as soon as I click on the row and because of `inlineEditing` the row gets selected as well as the checkbox for such row, how do I avoid to edit the row when check|uncheck the select?

Comment: @ReynierPM: I'm not sure that I understand what you *want* to implement. `onSelectRow` starts inline editing depend on the column which is clicked (not on click on `act` column). One can use `beforeSelectRow` to prevent selection on some clicks. On the other side there are many other options, which can change the behavior of selection in general. See https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.2/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L1152-L1170

Comment: Try this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aw47ytqz/2/) click on any column `inlineEditing` will happen and the checkbox at the first column gets checked. Try to uncheck the checkbox to stop the `inlineEditing` you can't. You have to click on the `Cancel` button no matter what. I want to avoid this behavior. As soon as you try to uncheck the checkbox `inlineEditing` should stop

Comment: @ReynierPM: What you want to prevent: selection or inline editing?

Comment: And even if you click on the `Cancel` button the checkbox still checked and the line still marked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163272/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-oleg).